# Converting a font from SVG to SBIX

Tags: fonts, conversion, svg

I've created a colored SVG font in the TTF container file using this project: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font

However, macOS and iOS only support SBIX fonts, not SVG. They end up showing the SVGs as black outlines. So I want to convert this to an SBIX font. What tools are available to do that?

I've tried converting a subset of Twitter Color Emoji using TransType 4, which claims to have this functionality, but it's not rendering the SVGs correctly; many shapes are in the wrong place both in the app and in the exported font.

I've also looked at the FontTools Python package and the TTX font it produces. I'm able to manually change some images by editing the PNG hexadecimal-encoded data, but that's about it. It gets too complicated to add or remove characters with all the ligatures and other scripts involved.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yeah, I did look at those two, as I mentioned in the third and fourth paragraphs. I'm currently messing with a TTX file some more to see where I can get.